# How to stop Synergy screen flicker

Tags: ubuntu, display, nvidia-graphics-card, synergy

My configuration:

- Synergy 1.4.10
- Windows 7 laptop server
- Ubuntu 12.04 Client w/ Dual HP Monitors
- NVIDIA driver Version 295.40

I have done many, many hours of research on this, and the usual solutions simply do not work:

- xset -dpms
- remove Option "DPMS" from xorg.conf
- uninstall screensaver

What else can I try?

Answer (score 1):

`xset -dpms` worked when I was going from a linux guest to a windows host and the linux host was flickering a while ago. Anyways, now my dev environment is full linux on multiple computers, and this problem persisted. What I found as a super hackish way to leave me feeling like all like 'There, I fixed it!' - This was starting the client machine's synergy instance, then rapidly cycling from the host the mouse over to the other box. This somehow prevents the screen flicker for happening, at least until I take off from my desk for a bit and come back with the screensaver stuff jangling things up again. Considering that I got actual work to do, it's good enough for now (Or at least until the developer quits being infuriating and starts distributing updates of his application for free again rather than his sick, perverted idea of how open source software should be distributed!)